# How is data replicated among 2 different TiKv clusters?

Tags: tikv

Suppose I have one TiKV cluster deployed in city A and another TiKV cluster deployed in city B. And I want to write data in cluster A and read it in cluster B.

I know that inside cluster A, the data security is enforced by multi-group raft. But how can the data in cluster A be replicated to cluster B and always kept updated? How can inter-cluster replication is performed?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you deploy one Cluster in city A. And then add one learner replica in city B. Then you can read data in city B directly by follower read.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one of the TiKV cluster between city A and city B, and then use the follower-read feature for this scene.

https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/follower-read#follower-read